# WPF datagrid sort bug

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to get my column to sort using the datagrid `SortMemberPath="COLUMN"` attribute and I get a weird sort order like so:

[image]

It looks like the column is sorted on the basis of the first digit of the number and not the entire number. How can I fix this?

Edit:

Okay, I see what the problem is. I'm using this converter now but still no change.

```
public class IntToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            string s = (string)value;
            int num;
            if (int.TryParse(s, out num))
                return Int32.Parse(s);
        }
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        int number = (int)value;
        return number.ToString();
    }
}
```

I added this to my xaml file Windows.Resource:

```
<me:IntToStringConverter x:Key="IntToStringConverter"/>
```

and made this change in my data part:

```
<toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MinRun, Converter={StaticResource IntToStringConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Here is the DataGrid part of the XAML. Note that out of all the columns, I'm first trying to get the 'MinRun' column to sort properly first, then I'll use the same technique on the other columns.

http://pastebin.com/ec14p4ks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's doing a string sort, which suggests to me that you're binding that column to a String property.  Change the property to be an integer type, and DataGrid will sort correctly.

In my experience, programmers make the property a string type because they want to, for example, to display a blank string when the value is invalid.  Use a ValueConverter for that instead, so you have the flexibility of displaying any string you want while WPF does a numeric sort on the underlying data.

Comment: How would I do the binding? I'm a bit new to WPF, sorry.

Comment: The same way you're doing it now.  There are several ways of doing it.  Since you're seeing data in your DataGrid, stick with what you're doing.  Simply change the data type.

Answer (score 2):

Your column is probably bound to a `String` object.
Therefore, the sort do an alphabetic job, not a numeric.

You should bind your column to `int` values.

Comment: Okay, I see. I'm using this converter now but I still dont see any change.

Comment: Did you checked if your converter works ? When your DataGrid is populated, can you check if you have integers in your column ?

Comment: I went about putting a breakpoint in the 'return num' line and debugging in visual studio to see if it was returning ints from the strings it read in and it was working. I checked the values of the variables and sure enough, the input value was "6" and returned value of num was 6.
When I clicked the header of the column to sort while debugging mode, I hit the breakpoint again for each of the values. And yet, the sort was not correct.

Comment: Could you provide us the code of your `DataGridView` ? Since it's probably big, I think it is a good idea to put it in a Pastebin

Comment: How do I use Pastebin? There is no info on it in editing mode.
Also, I noticed something interesting while debugging.  When I click the column header to sort, I hit the 'return num' statement in the same order as in the image above.  So it appears that the column is sorted before the numbers are converted to ints.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, this is not part of StackOverflow, go here : http://pastebin.com/ You will be provided a link that you can give us afterwards :)

Answer (score 0):

**Given**

A DataGrid showing a collection of TestResults where elapsed time was converted to string in the model.  When bound to the DataGrid sorting was by string and not numeric value.

Solution shown below: The `var qry` was a `List` of a custom-type with the property `TestElapsedTime` of type `Double`.

**Add a Sorting Event Handler to DataGrid**

```html
  <DataGrid x:Name="testResultsDataGrid" Sorting="OnSorting">
```

**In the EventHandler**

```
    private void OnSorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
    {
        var col = e.Column.Header.ToString();
        if (col == "Elapsed Time")
        {
            var qry = GetCollectionViewSourceDefaultView();
            qry.Sort((x, y) =>
            {
                var diff = x.TestElapsedTime - y.TestElapsedTime;
                return (int)diff;
            });
        }
    }
```

**Problems**

The elapsed time was a double so the lambda had to perform a cast to int as shown.

**Surprises**

The direction of the sort is determined by the displayed datagrid, it knows how to use the one sort function to sort both directions!

Answer (score -2):

Luckly for me i could change the original class, but I'm interested in the answer.

I added a readonly integer property.

Comment: This does not seem to be an answer.